# Oracle SQL Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Tags: oracle

I am trying to run the following SQL code in Oracle and keep getting the following error:

> Error at line 1: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

I get this error for all 6 of my tables that I try to generate. I am not sure why I am getting this error, as I believe I am using all the proper keys and constraints.

```
create table Bands (        
  band_id int NOT NULL,        
  name varchar(80) NOT NULL,        
  genre varchar(20),        
  primary key(band_id),        
  unique(name)
);

create table Users (        
  user_id int NOT NULL,        
  name varchar(80),        
  favorite_band_id int,        
  primary key(user_id),        
  foreign key(favorite_band_id) references Bands,        
  unique(favorite_band_id)
);        

create table Groups (        
  group_id int NOT NULL,        
  name varchar(80) NOT NULL,        
  description varchar(255),        
  favorite_band_id int,        
  primary key(group_id),        
  foreign key(favorite_band_id) references Bands,        
  unique(favorite_band_id,name)
);    

create table Note (        
  note_id int NOT NULL,        
  user_id int NOT NULL,        
  text varchar(255),        
  primary key(note_id),        
  foreign key(user_id) references Users,        
  unique(user_id)
);    

create table BelongsTo (        
  user_id int NOT NULL,        
  group_id int NOT NULL,        
  private char(1),        
  primary key(user_id,group_id),        
  foreign key(user_id) references Users,        
  foreign key(group_id) references Groups,        
  CHECK(private = 0 OR private = 1)
);    

create table InvitedTo (        
  group_id int NOT NULL,        
  invitor_id int NOT NULL,        
  invitee_id int NOT NULL,        
  primary key(group_id,invitor_id,invitee_id),        
  foreign key(group_id) references Groups,        
  foreign key(invitor_id,invitee_id) references Users
);
```

Comment: Just to clarify: The question is tagged as an Oracle question.  The error mentioned is an Oracle error (ORA-00955).  Is it really MySQL?  Or Oracle? (The syntax does not look like MySQL).

Comment: Sorry about that. It is Oracle, but I meant to say SQL code, not mySQL.